# SQL: View Representing Missing Ranges

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given a table of rows each representing a numerical range.

```
CREATE TABLE ranges (
    start INTEGER,
    end INTEGER
)
```

How could I create a view that represents the "holes" in the ranges? (Ignoring the bounds from -infinity to +infinity).

For example if the table had the data:

```
(1,3)
(4,5)
(8,10)
(16,20)
```

The result I'd like is:

```
(6,7)
(11,15)
```

I'm using python and sqlite. I'm currently thinking that a using a procedural approach in a sqlite function or python might be the most clear and performant approach.

I've seen an approach for finding missing dates that rely on a temp table for all the possible dates, but this method isn't feasible for integer ranges as they could very large.

Comment: This is a classic [gaps and islands](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/) problem. Lots of interesting ways to go about this one, none of them are plainly obvious though :)

Comment: @JNevill Nice! I knew it was a common problem but didn't know what it was called to search for it. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to do this as:

```
select (start + 1) as missing_start, (next_start - 1) as missing_ne
from (select t.*,
             (select min(t2.start)
              from t t2
              where t2.start > t.start
             ) as next_start
      from t
     ) t
where next_start > end + 1;
```

Note that this assumes no overlaps.  If overlaps are possible the problem can be more difficult to solve.